# Automate AWS pipeline creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I want to dynamically create different no of pipelines daily. Can you suggest the best way to do that? Simply I want to automate my pipeline creation process. Highly appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: You need to explain what kind of pipeline you are talking about? Also what you have tried so far and what was your outcome?

Comment: I want to migrate data from redshift to Aurora via S3 some key-wise. But the problem is I want to do it daily and I got different no of keys for each day. So I want to automate this process.
As an example supposes for today I have 34 keys, and I decided to run pipeline per 10 keys, I need to activate four pipelines for today. Likewise I need a best method to do that. My keys are stored in S3 file.